# Zeroes after each value that has been sent over serial communication

Tags: c++, serial-port

I try to learn C++ by doing everything on it. However, I stuck while establishing serial communication over C++. I send an integer array over MCU(microcontroller) to the VS C++. I have no any software problem on the MCU side(I have tested). Additionally I can read char values correctly. However, when I read values by C++ I get 0 after each integer I read. I couldn't solve the problem, while I think that 0 corresponds to the newline. 
For example if I send (5, 10, 15), I read (5, 0, 10, 0, 15, 0).
Can you help me in order to solve the problem? I am using Windows Api for serial communication.
The relevant code:

```
char  ReadData;        //temperory Character
int SerialBuffer[64] = { 0 }; //Buffer to send and receive data
```

.
.
.

```
    do
        {
            Status = ReadFile(hComm, &ReadData, sizeof(ReadData), &NoBytesRead, NULL);
            SerialBuffer[loop] = ReadData;
            ++loop;
        } while (NoBytesRead > 0);
```

The whole code:

```
int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hComm;  // Handle to the Serial port
    BOOL   Status; // Status
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };  // Initializing DCB structure
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };  //Initializing timeouts structure
    int SerialBuffer[64] = { 0 }; //Buffer to send and receive data
    DWORD BytesWritten = 0;          // No of bytes written to the port
    DWORD dwEventMask;     // Event mask to trigger
    char  ReadData;        //temperory Character
    DWORD NoBytesRead;     // Bytes read by ReadFile()
    unsigned char loop = 0;
    wchar_t pszPortName[10] = { 0 }; //com port id
    wchar_t PortNo[20] = { 0 }; //contain friendly name

    hComm = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM6", //friendly name
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,      // Read/Write Access
        0,                                 // No Sharing, ports cant be shared
        NULL,                              // No Security
        OPEN_EXISTING,                     // Open existing port only
        0,                                 // Non Overlapped I/O
        NULL);                             // Null for Comm Devices
    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf_s("\n Port can't be opened\n\n");
    }
    //Setting the Parameters for the SerialPort
    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    Status = GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams); //retreives  the current settings
    if (Status == FALSE)
    {
        printf_s("\nError to Get the Com state\n\n");
    }
    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_115200;      //BaudRate = 9600
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;             //ByteSize = 8
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    //StopBits = 1
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;      //Parity = None
    Status = SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);
    if (Status == FALSE)
    {
        printf_s("\nError to Setting DCB Structure\n\n");
    }
    //Setting Timeouts
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    if (SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts) == FALSE)
    {
        printf_s("\nError to Setting Time outs");

    }
    Status = SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR);
    if (Status == FALSE)
    {
        printf_s("\nError to in Setting CommMask\n\n");

    }
    //Setting WaitComm() Event
    Status = WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwEventMask, NULL); //Wait for the character to be received
    if (Status == FALSE)
    {
        printf_s("\nError! in Setting WaitCommEvent()\n\n");
    }
    //Read data and store in a buffer
    do
    {
        Status = ReadFile(hComm, &ReadData, sizeof(ReadData), &NoBytesRead, NULL);
        SerialBuffer[loop] = ReadData;
        ++loop;
    } while (NoBytesRead > 0);
    --loop; //Get Actual length of received data
    printf_s("\nNumber of bytes received = %d\n\n", loop);
    //print receive data on console
    printf_s("\n\n");
    int index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < loop; ++index)
    {
        printf_s("%d    ", SerialBuffer[index]);
    }
    printf_s("\n\n");

    CloseHandle(hComm);//Closing the Serial Port
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might want to check the size of the values you are sending? Sounds like your might have a mismatch there. i.e. sending them as 64 bit and reading them as 32 bit.

Comment: Probably the cause is that (As from MCU I send 16 bit int). I will check and write. Thank you very much :)